# Where is the "Install Profile" value in the Status report set?

Tags: 7, installation-profiles

I am using Drupal 7. If I go to Reports --> Status Report, the "Install Profile" value is incorrect (it has an extra dash at the end). Where is this value stored? I wish to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The displayed name comes from the `name` key in the profile's `.info` file. If you change `name` you must clear the site caches to see a change on the report.